# checked checkbox become unchecked in recyclerview after scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-checkbox

I have a recyclerview with a list of items , when i check an item and scroll until the checked checkbox disppear , and scroll again to it , the checkbox become unchecked

this is my adapter code

```
class ContactsAdapter(var list:ArrayList<contact>, private val listener: (contact) -> Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.viewHolder>() {

    inner class viewHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_ui, parent, false)
        return viewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewHolder, position: Int) {
        var itemPosition = list[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            contact_name.text=itemPosition.contactName
            contact_number.text=itemPosition.contactNumber[0]
            check_number.setOnClickListener {
                listener(itemPosition)
            }
            check_number.isChecked = itemPosition.checked
}
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return list.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` recycles its rows. Your `setOnClickListener()` needs to do something to hold onto which items are checked and unchecked, and your `onBindViewHolder()` needs to update the `CheckBox` when it binds an item. It seems like the second part is implemented, but perhaps not the first part. You may need to update `itemPosition.checked` in your lambda for `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Thanks , i followed your instructions and the check saved , but i have another problem , let's say that i have 20 item , and i checked number 3 , when i keep scrolling i found random items also checked !

Comment: @AnasHafidi: A `RecyclerView` recycles its rows. This means that a `CheckBox` for some previous item will be reused for some new item as the user scrolls. Make sure that you always update your `CheckBox` in every `onBindViewHolder()` call to reflect the checked state of the newly-bound item. Beyond that, use debugging or `Log` calls to see where/how you are updating the `CheckBox` widgets and where/how you are updating the data based on the user checking the `CheckBox`.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i fix it with your instructions .